# how do write a UDF for serializing a field

Tags: mysql, serialization

I would like to ask how can I write a MySQL UDF for serializing a field with the same key field.

I have

```
  key1       value1
  key1       value2
  key1       value3
  key2       value1
```

and would like to get

```
 key1       value1,value2,value3
 key2       value1
```

Can anyone here tell me how it can be done?

thanks
Walter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need [`Group_Concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) functionality:

```
SELECT 
  key_column_name, Group_Concat(value_column_name) 
FROM your_table_name 
GROUP BY key_column_name
```